# How to create login page with vue.js and html?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

We have a small project at which I want to create a login page that takes data from a vue data list and if the data corresponds with the username and passwords introduced in html it will load a new page. I don't exactly know how to properly take and check the data from the vue data list and I searched in the documentation for a while but I got lost and didn't find how exactly to do it so any help would be awesome.

This is the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/vue/vue.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/axios/axios.js"></script>
    <script src="login.js" defer></script>

</head>
<body id="indexbody">
<div class="Login" id="Login"> 
    <div class="container">
        <h1>LOGIN</h1>
        <form id="login-form" method="post">
            <div class="text-field">
                <input type="text" name="username" required autocomplete="off"/>
                <span></span>
                <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
            </div>
            <div class="text-field">
                <input type="password" name="password" required autocomplete="off"/>
                <span></span>
                <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
            </div>
            <div class="LoginBTN">
                <input type="button" value="Login" id="loginBTN" onclick="validate(this.form)"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the js file:

```
var login = new Vue({
    el: "#Login",
    data: {
        loginUsers: [{
            "username":"admin",
            "password":"admin"
        },
        {
            "username":"Razvan",
            "password":"parolamea"
        }]
    },
    
    methods: {
    }
});

function validate(form){
    var un=form.username.value;
    var pw=form.password.value;
    for(var users in loginUsers){
        if(un==users.username && pw==users.password){
            window.location='table.html';
            return;
        }
        else{
            alert("Login failed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"How to create login page with vue.js and html?"_, _"how to properly take ... the data from the vue data list"_ and _"how to properly ... check the data from the vue data list"_ are three different questions. What's you're actual question? What are you struggling with?

Comment: @jabaa The main problem is that the login page is not functioning which includes both the "how to properly take data from a vue data list" and "how to properly check that data from the vue data list" I don't know how do take make that properly because I'm new to this so that implies that I might've done things wrong even at the page's level which also implies that the problem could be to the page's level which correlates with the question I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For use the Vue instance variables you have to bind some model variables to the inputs, and move the validate function to a method of the Vue instance. Something like this:

for the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/vue/vue.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/axios/axios.js"></script>
    <script src="login.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body id="indexbody">
<div class="Login" id="Login">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>LOGIN</h1>
        <form id="login-form" method="post">
            <div class="text-field">
                <input v-model="username" type="text" name="username" required autocomplete="off"/>
                <span></span>
                <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
            </div>
            <div class="text-field">
                <input v-model="password" type="password" name="password" required autocomplete="off"/>
                <span></span>
                <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
            </div>
            <div class="LoginBTN">
                <input type="button" value="Login" id="loginBTN" @click="validate()"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this for the js file:

```
var login = new Vue({
    el: "#Login",
    data: {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        loginUsers: [{
            "username":"admin",
            "password":"admin"
        },
        {
            "username":"Razvan",
            "password":"parolamea"
        }]
    },

    methods: {
        validate() {
            const un = this.username;
            const pw = this.password;
            for(var userIndex in this.loginUsers){
                const user = this.loginUsers[userIndex];
                if(un==user.username && pw==user.password){
                    window.location='table.html';
                    return;
                }
            }
            alert("Login failed");
        }
    }
});
```